# Why does stop_token notify_all()?

Tags: c++, condition-variable

libstdc++ `condition_variable_any` uses `notify_all()` in the `stop_callback`. This means when a stop is requested, all threads waiting on that condvar are notified, including threads using other stop sources and threads in uninterruptible waits.

Why does this implementation not make an effort to notify only those threads using the stop source in question?

Comment: _"...Why does this implementation not make an effort to notify only those threads using the stop source in question?..."_ - `std::condition_variable_any::notify_all` - Unblocks all threads currently waiting for `*this`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/notify_all

Comment: I know it wakes only those threads waiting on the current condition variable. But among those threads, not all might be using the same stop source, or any stop source at all.